# How to find out Date/Month interval between @StartDate and @EndDate passed in stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a stored procedure where I am dividing the number of rows by interval of month and day repeated in the specified date range.

Interval Month and Day = 7th April and 8th October

**Example** 
For Date range 2014/01/01 and 2014/12/31, 7th April and 8th October are repeated 2 times so I will divide my statement by 2.

For Date range 2014/01/01 and 2015/09/01, 7th April came 2 and 8th October 1 so I will divide my statement by 3.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you're asking here.  Are you just trying to find the number of days between two dates, or the number of months between two dates?  If so, you probably want the function DATEDIFF().  If you want something else, could you please give an example of what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: All I am asking is how many times 7th April and 8th October are repeating within the selected period excluding year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, the question is a bit unclear, but I believe I know what you're trying to do. You are trying to find the number of times that a set of dates (only taking Month/Day into account) happen over a range of dates (set by `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`). I think the `select count(*) from TableName` part of the question is a distraction, as you already know how to do that. Below is an answer on how to get the denominator, which is what you are trying to figure out how to do.

```
declare @StartDate date = '2014-01-01'
    , @EndDate date = '2014-12-31'
    , @DenVal int --Denominator Value

create table #dates_of_interest
    (
        month_nbr tinyint not null
        , day_nbr tinyint not null
    )

insert into #dates_of_interest
values (4, 7) --7th of April
    , (10, 8) --8th of October

; with date_list as
    (
        --use a Recursive CTE to generate a list of all the dates in the given range.
        select @StartDate as dt
        union all
        select dateadd(d,1,dt) as dt
        from date_list
        where 1=1
        and dt < @EndDate
    )
--Get the output of the Recursive CTE along with Month/Day numbes
select dt
, datepart(m,dt) as month_nbr
, datepart(d,dt) as day_nbr
into #list_of_dates
from date_list as dl
option (maxrecursion 32767) --set to max possible levels of recursion (might want to lower this number) 

--Set the Denominator to the results of the sum(case/when) AKA countif
set @DenVal = 
    (
        select sum(case when di.month_nbr is null and di.day_nbr is null then 0 else 1 end) 
        from #list_of_dates as ld
        left join #dates_of_interest as di on ld.month_nbr = di.month_nbr
                                          and ld.day_nbr = di.day_nbr   
    )

Print @DenVal
```

Both examples of 1/1/2014 - 12/31/2014 and 1/1/2014 - 9/1/2015 come up with the desired results of 2 and 3 respectively. There may be other ways of accomplishing this, but I thought that a [Recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) was the best option.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.